# In Flutter how do I read an asset that's in a Deferred Component using rootBundle.load()?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, assets, android-app-bundle

I have a Flutter app with some assets arriving via Deferred Components. The YAML looks something like this:

```
deferred-components:
     - name: arBlock11
       assets:
          - assets/unity/ch1/1/
          - assets/unity/ch1/2/
          - assets/unity/ch1/3/
```

And I'm attempting to read the files like this:

```
ByteData assetFile = await rootBundle.load('assets/unity/ch1/1/big.file.ecm');
```

When I test locally, this works. But when I test in the Play Store with real Deferred Components downloading, I get this error:

```
01-10 19:19:32.552 15229 15267 E flutter : [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/unity/ch1/1/big.file.ecm
```

What gives? How do I access the actual file of an asset in a Deferred Component?

Thank you!